# Getting IAT and EAT from PE

Tags: python, portable-executable

Can someone suggest how using python i can get  Import address table
and  Export address table form PE? I currently using pefile module, but not sure i can get IAT and EAT using it.
Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150406070810/http://code.google.com/p/pefile/wiki/UsageExamples) describes how to do it:

**Listing the imported symbols**

Each directory, if it exists in the PE file being processed, has an entry as DIRECTORY_ENTRY_directoryname in the PE instance. The imported symbols can be listed as follows:

```
# If the PE file was loaded using the fast_load=True argument, we will need to parse the data directories:
pe.parse_data_directories()

for entry in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT:
  print entry.dll
  for imp in entry.imports:
    print '\t', hex(imp.address), imp.name
```

**Output**

```
comdlg32.dll
        0x10012A0L PageSetupDlgW
        0x10012A4L FindTextW
        0x10012A8L PrintDlgExW
[snip]
SHELL32.dll
        0x1001154L DragFinish
        0x1001158L DragQueryFileW
```

**Listing the exported symbols**

Similarly, the exported symbols can be listed as follows:

```
for exp in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT.symbols:
  print hex(pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.ImageBase + exp.address), exp.name, exp.ordinal
```

**Output**

```
0x7ca0ab4f SHUpdateRecycleBinIcon 336
0x7cab44c0 SHValidateUNC 173
0x7ca7b0aa SheChangeDirA 337
0x7ca7b665 SheChangeDirExA 338
0x7ca7b3e1 SheChangeDirExW 339
0x7ca7aec6 SheChangeDirW 340
0x7ca8baae SheConvertPathW 341
```